# How using python scan through dir tree to find single files in subfolders

Tags: windows, list, python-2.7

I would like to scan through the directory tree to find directories which contain a single file with extension .doc in it. 
Ignore directories which contain 2 or more of the same file type.

This is under windows with python 2.7.x.

So for and instance below dir contain 2 files with the same extension - the script should not list this dir:

c:\temp\dir1\file1.doc
c:\temp\dir1\file2.doc

But it should list below dirs:
c:\temp\dir2\file3.doc
C:\temp\something.doc
etc.

Can you help me with that?

I have something like this:

```
import os
noOfmp3 = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
        noOfmp3 += 1
        if noOfmp3 > 1:
            print(os.path.join(root, file)), noOfmp3
```

The problem is that it counts all the files in all the dirst and it sums them up.
I would like to count number of files in each dir.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? We'd like to help you if you show us what you've done and where you got stuck. But SO is no free coding service.

Comment: Search for `os.walk`.  There are many examples on SO, but it helps to know what to look for.

Comment: I have updated my post with the code. Can you please advise now?

Comment: My code prints out just every MP3 file within any directory. So even when there are more than 1 mp3 in a dir - it will print all of them. And that is NOT what i want. I would like to have only listed directories in which there are single, only 1 MP3 in each.
Please advise how to do it. Im new in Python and still learning. I have my little own learning project and i got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "os.walk", to literally walk thru directories.
Check this out:

> os.walk(top[, topdown=True[, onerror=None[, followlinks=False]]])

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

To read more about this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html